# How to add male voice data files into pico tts engine?

Tags: android, voice, text-to-speech

How can i add male voice data files into pico tts engine in android?

Answer (score 0):

Android offers from some languages lot of voices and it is specified if they are male or female.

So you can download a male voice if it is offered by google.

> 1. Language and Input
> 2. Text-to-speech options
> 3. On preferred tts engine click settings;
> 4. Install voice data;
> 5. Check if there is a male one for your preferred language;

Then you can set the voice in your app. You can use getVoices() to have a Set of all avaible voices and you can set which one you want by checking its ID.